# Some kind of latin squares

Tags: graph-theory, latin-square

Consider we have an $n\times n$ square. And for each element $a_{ij}$ there is a $L_{ij}$ set of permissible values(numbers) where $|L_{ij}| = n - 1$. Need to choose a value for each $a_{ij}$ element so that no orthogonal (row or column) contains the same number twice.

Where can I read about such kind of squares? Any books or links?

Or any information about squares where we are choosing value of each element from it's permissible set.

Comment: Why is this tagged graph-theory? Please share us what you know.

Comment: @JiK, as you can see in below comments latin rectangles can be represented as colorings of graphs. For more info you can google ;)
[latin rectangles](https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&q=latin+rectangle+graph+theory)

Answer (score 2):

In general that can't be done. Suppose $L_{ij}=\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ for all $i,j$. How are you going to choose the values for the top row without repeating a number?

If you meant $|L_{ij}|=n$ instead of $|L_{ij}|=n-1$, look up "Dinitz problem".

Comment: You're talking about Dinitz conjecture for $K_{nn}$ bipartite graph and it's known that list-chromatic index of $K_{nn}$ is $n$. I just want to find any information about squares where we're choosing value for each element from it's list. Let's forget about size of lists for now.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be rephrased in terms of [list colourings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_coloring) of the graph with vertices $a_{ij}$ and edges $a_{ij}a_{i'j'}$ whenever $i=i'$ or $j=j'$. If you think about it for a bit, you'll see that this graph is $K_n \square K_n$, the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs) of two complete graphs.

With this in mind, you might find [a paper on list colourings of Cartesian products of graphs](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2006.03.062) relevant.

Comment: I'm just trying to go behind list colorings from this side.